# Wifi Monitor mode with 802.11b only and fixed Data Rate

Tags: wireless-networking, wifi-configuration, packet-injection

Hi All i have put my wifi dongle in monitor mode and receive only 802.11b packets in ubuntu machine.

```
sudo ifconfig wxc12003 down
sudo iw dev wxc12003 set monitor otherbss fcsfail
sudo ifconfig wxc12003 up
sudo iw wxc12003 set channel 3 HT20
```

1. I wanted to know why i am getting broadcast frames only (802.11b) with 1 Mbps  data rate.
2. How can i inject packet and send with DSSS applied with data rate of fixed 6.0 Mbps. Can i set any standard data rate mentioned below

running iw list i get following supported data rates

```
Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 1.0 Mbps
            * 2.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 5.5 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 11.0 Mbps (short preamble supported)
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: In monitor mode, i want to inject packet and send with DSSS modulation along with data rate of 6.0 mbps to enable receiver (same dongle) to receive packet in case interference exists.